# Expected value of a Stochastic process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, random-walks, expectation

Consider a discrete stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ with the following properties. Each $t \in T$ has a value $v(t) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and the value is added to the overall value conditioned on some event $\mathbb{1}_t = 1$; that is, $X_t = v(t) \cdot \mathbb{1}_t$. In addition, for every $t \in T$ the expected value added by the *next* increase after $t$ is bounded by one, that is: Let $n(t)$ be the first time $s$ after time $t$ in which $\mathbb{1}_s = 1$, then assume that
$\mathbb{E} [X_{n(t)}] \leq 1$ for all $t \in T$.

**Question:** Using what we know on $X_{n(t)}$, can we give an upper bound on the overall value $\mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{t \in T} X_t \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{t \in T} \frac{X_{n(t)}}{\sum_{s \in T ~s.t.~ n(s) = n(t)}} \right]$? or an upper bound on the expected value of a single added value $\mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{\sum_{t \in T} X_t}{\sum_{t \in T} \mathbb{1}_t}\right]$?